# ¿Porque me aparece Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

Buenas he estado buscando la razón por el cual me sale este error. He leido que es por la ubicación del script y que se recomienda ponerlo al final del todo ya que la lectura de JS es de arriba abajo, pero aun así me sigue apareciendo el mismo error. Aquí dejo mi codigo:

```css
div#contenedor .subcontenedor {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px ;
    grid-template-rows: 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px ;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
/*    visibility: hidden; */
}

div#contenedor .item {
    background-color:darkcyan;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid darkblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="Estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
           <h3>Numero Primos</h3>
            <label for="numero">Numero</label>
            <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="Introduce un número">
            <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Generar"
            onclick="generarNAleatorio();"> 
        </form>
        
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="subcontenedor">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            
            function generarNAleatorio(){
                
                var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").value);
                var cantidad = 2;
                var inicio = 1;
                var indicador = 0;
                var contador = 0;
                var indice = 0;
                
            while(contador<=50){ 
                
                 while (inicio<=num){
                    if (num%inicio == 0){
                        indicador+=1;
                    }
                    inicio++;
                }
                
                if(indicador == 2){
                    document.getElementsByClassName("item")[indice].innerHTML = num;
                    contador ++;
                    indice++;
                }
                num += 1;
                indicador = 0;
                inicio = 1;
            }
            
           // document.getElementById("contenedor").style.visibility = "visible";    
                
        }        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Me sigue funcionando el proceso, pero me da ese error. A que se debe o como puedo corregirlo? Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: El error está aquí: `document.getElementsByClassName("item")[indice].innerHTML = num;` Esa sintaxis es incorrecta. Si quieres seleccionar los elementos de una clase dinámica, que se llamaría por ejemplo `item5` donde `5` es el valor actual de la variable `indice`. Entonces tienes que hacerlo así: `document.getElementsByClassName("item"+indice).innerHTML = num;`. No sé si sea exactamente esa la *intención* de tu código, pero es lo que parece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error:  `while(contador <= 50)` , por qué?

Tienes 50 elementos, la variable contador **empieza** desde 0, entonces el primer elemento tendrá índice 0 y el último 49.

Solución: `while(contador < 50)`, además he creado una función `probarError()`, para que lo compruebes.

```js
function generarNAleatorio(){
                
                var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").value);
                var cantidad = 2;
                var inicio = 1;
                var indicador = 0;
                var contador = 0;
                var indice = 0;
                
            while(contador<50){ 
                
                 while (inicio<=num){
                    if (num%inicio == 0){
                        indicador+=1;
                    }
                    inicio++;
                }
                
                if(indicador == 2){
                    document.getElementsByClassName("item")[indice].innerHTML = num;
                    contador ++;
                    indice++;
                }
                num += 1;
                indicador = 0;
                inicio = 1;
            }
            
           // document.getElementById("contenedor").style.visibility = "visible";    
                
        }
        
        function probarError(){
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
        for(var i =0 ,a = Array.from(items), l = a.length; i<=l;i++){ if(typeof a[i] === "undefined") {
         console.log(`El error está en el índice: ${i}`);
        }  }
        
        }
        probarError();
```

```css
div#contenedor .subcontenedor {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px ;
    grid-template-rows: 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px ;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
/*    visibility: hidden; */
}

div#contenedor .item {
    background-color:darkcyan;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid darkblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="Estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
           <h3>Numero Primos</h3>
            <label for="numero">Numero</label>
            <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="Introduce un número">
            <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Generar"
            onclick="generarNAleatorio();"> 
        </form>
        
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="subcontenedor">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correcto tiene toda la razón, no había caído en eso de los indices de los elementos, obviamente uno no existe. Muchas gracias por ayudarme!

Answer (score -1):

cambia esto *while(contador <= 50)* por esto **while(contador < 50)** o **while(contador <= 49)**

ya que tienes 50 item y el contador lo empiezas por 0 por lo tanto de 0 al 49 hay 50 posiciones